# Fresh install readthedocs, connecting to github

Tags: python, django, read-the-docs

I am following this tutorial of how to install readthedocs locally.

https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

Everything works as expected, however there is a thing I cannot wrap my head around.

I have created user, activated him by clicking confirmation link and then in admin I tried to connect to github. What I get on this point is:

```
DoesNotExist at /accounts/github/login/callback/

SocialApp matching query does not exist.
```

Quick and dirty solution is to add github app in the admin (/admin/socialaccount/socialapp/add/) however in such case when I click connect account will be simply connected to that github account (and any other user will be prevented from connecting to anything).

What do I miss in my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

As it happens there is known missing step on installation.

More on the topic here:

https://github.com/rtfd/readthedocs.org/issues/1619

However so far I have no clue what to configure in order to get rid of this error and allow two different user to connect their own git projects.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the admin and add a social app:
http://localhost:8000/admin/socialaccount/socialapp/add/

**Steps to create a new github app:**

1. App registration (get your key and secret here)

   https://github.com/settings/applications/new
2. Development callback URL

   http://localhost:8000/accounts/github/login/callback/